# Group data according to frequency of values in a column in a data frame using R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, frequency

I have a data frame like the following:

```
a  b
1  23
2  34
1  34
3  45
1  56
3  567
2  67
2  90
1  91
3  98
```

I want to get the data frame with rows grouped according to the frequency of values in the first column. The output should be like the following:

```
a  b  freq
1  23   4
1  34   4
1  56   4
1  91   4
2  34   3
2  67   3
2  90   3
3  45   3
3  567  3
3  98   3
```

I have written the following code in R:

```
import library(dplyr)
setDT(df)[,freq := .N, by = "a"]
sorted = df[order(freq, decreasing = T),]
sorted
```

However, I get the following data frame as the output.

```
    a  b freq
 1: 1  23    4
 2: 1  34    4
 3: 1  56    4
 4: 1  91    4
 5: 2  34    3
 6: 3  45    3
 7: 3  567   3
 8: 2  67    3
 9: 2  90    3
10: 3  98    3
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please check your expected output.  In the input data, the 567 comes under a = 3.  In the expected it is on a = 2.

Comment: I have edited the output.

Comment: by the way, the syntax you are using is from the library `data.table` and not `dplyr`.

Comment: @akrun Your answer is not visible. Could you post it again?

Comment: @AsmitaPoddar  Could you please refresh the webpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `n()`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(a) %>%
    mutate(freq = n()) %>%
    arrange(a, desc(freq))
# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   a [3]
#       a     b  freq
#  <int> <int> <int>
# 1     1    23     4
# 2     1    34     4
# 3     1    56     4
# 4     1    91     4
# 5     2    34     3
# 6     2    67     3
# 7     2    90     3
# 8     3    45     3
# 9     3   567     3
#10     3    98     3
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to use `setorder` from `data.table` package.
You have ordered your data by `freq`, but you want also to apply order on column `a`.

`setorder` example:

```
> set.seed(12)
> df <- data.table(freq = sample(5, 5), a = sample(5, 5))
> df
   freq a
1:    1 1
2:    4 5
3:    3 2
4:    5 4
5:    2 3
> setorder(df, freq, a)
> df
   freq a
1:    1 1
2:    2 3
3:    3 2
4:    4 5
5:    5 4
```

Comment: How will I use it? Could you give me the code to solve this  problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
> df <- read.table(text = 'a  b
+ 1  23
+ 2  34
+ 1  34
+ 3  45
+ 1  56
+ 3  567
+ 2  67
+ 2  90
+ 1  91
+ 3  98', header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
> 
> df %>% group_by(a) %>%
+   mutate(Freq = n()) %>%
+   ungroup() %>%
+   arrange(a)
# A tibble: 10 × 3
       a     b  Freq
   <int> <int> <int>
1      1    23     4
2      1    34     4
3      1    56     4
4      1    91     4
5      2    34     3
6      2    67     3
7      2    90     3
8      3    45     3
9      3   567     3
10     3    98     3
```